# bash intercepting error and stop in pipeline

Tags: bash, pipeline

I've been trying different things without success

so here is what I want to achieve

```bash
set -o pipefail
dump "$@" "$db" | compress | store "single" "$(backupName "$db")"

# I would want something that behaves a bit like this
# meaning if it dump fails, don't store
dump "$@" "$db" && {
  #migicGetStdout | compress | store "single" "$(backupName "$db")"
} || {
  echo failed
}
```

But it creates a empty file on failed dump

I'm lost with pipeline

I've tried things like

```bash
set -e
set -o pipefail

dump "${dumpCommonArgs[@]}" "${dumpDbArgs[@]}" "$@" "$db" > >(compress | store "single" "$(backupName "$db")")

# or

( compress | store "single" "$(backupName "$db")" ) < <(dump "$@" "$db") || return 2

# or 

## this way compress get the global $@ ... I don't understand that either
store "single" "$(backupName "$db")" < <(dump "${dumpCommonArgs[@]}" "${dumpDbArgs[@]}" "$@" "$db") > >(compress)


# there would be an easy one
dataToStore=$(dump "$@" "$db")
rc=$?
# but this means dump is stored in memory before saving... not the best deal as mysql already needs a lot of ram to run a dump
```

`store` function is still called!

So seems I'm missing something.

Thanks for helping me out

Comment: All parts of a pipeline _run at the same time_. So you can't conditionally start later ones depending on how the prior ones went: they _all_ get started simultaneously.

Comment: Of course, you can do what you're asking for if you dump to a file instead of to stdout.

Comment: It's also possible to make sure `dump` _starts_ dumping data and only start the other parts if it writes at least one line; but if that's what you want, please update the question to make it clear.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy looks like someone already suggested this test of 1 line min... Any solution is good as long as it doesn't store all the dump in ram before starting to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to store the output of `dump` temporarily; example with a variable:

```bash
if out=$(dump "$@" "$db")
then
    printf '%s\n' "$out" |
    compress |
    store "single" "$(backupName "$db")"
else
    echo failed 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

or test for the emptiness of stdout (is there's no output when it fails):

```bash
dump "$@" "$db" | {
    IFS='' read -r line

    [ -n "${line:+_}" ] || { echo failed 1>&2; exit 1; }

    { printf '%s\n' "$line"; cat; } |
    compress |
    store "single" "$(backupName "$db")"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your first script is the simple solution `out="$(dump ...)"` but it'll store all dump in ram first. How about second the second, does it dump line per line as it comes in? or does the process wait for all content to pile up in `$lines` before passing to stdout? If not, could it be improved to do so.  If it's too complicated then I'll just delete the stored file `if $? != 0` but I wanted to avoid that kind of 'hack'

Comment: @AntonyGibbs the 2nd solution only reads the first line in a variable, then decide to `exit` or `cat` depending on its value

Comment: I finally got the meaning of `printf '%s\n' "$line"; cat;`  ... @Fravadiba thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

based on @Fravadona answer I end up writing a more generic function and thought it would be nice to share it too.

could be saved as a `on-empty-return` in /usr/local/bin

not forget `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/on-empty-return`

then could be used anywhere :)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
set -u
set -o pipefail

##
# usage
# echo "" | on-empty-return 2 cat > /tmp/should-not-create-file || {
#    >&2 echo "test failed, file is untouched (status $?)";
# }
#
# outputs to stderr
# Error: stdin is empty. (on-empty-return)
# test failed, file untouched not touched (status 2)
#
# cmd1 | on-empty-return 2 cmd2 args
# to output direct to file use cat
# cmd1 | on-empty-return 2 cat > 'file'
#
# if cmd1 output is empty, cmd2 won't be executed and will return code 2
# otherwise it'll return status code of cmd2 (assuming we have 'set -o pipefail')
#
# arg1: returned status on empty - optional default: 1
onEmptyReturn() {
  local emptyRc=1
  local line
  local re='^[0-9]+$'
  [[ ${1-} =~ $re ]] && { emptyRc=$1; shift; }

  IFS='' read -r line

  [ -n "${line:+_}" ] || { >&2 echo "Error: stdin is empty. (${0##*/})"; return $emptyRc; }

  { printf '%s\n' "$line"; cat; } | "$@"

  return $?
}

onEmptyReturn "$@"

exit $?
```

Snippet on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2415644)

Edit: replace `$(basename "$0")` with `${0##*/}` and $line as local thanks to @CharlesDuffy

Comment: `$?` is the default exit status. Just `exit` with no arguments is identical, but so is the script ending on its own; the same is true for `return`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy removing `return $emptyRc` would not return status of `echo`?

Comment: I was referring to `return $?` at the very end. `return $emptyRc` of course makes sense.

Comment: BTW, to handle the case where there _is_ more than one line of output but the first line is empty, think about testing `read`'s exit status instead of testing `line`. Since `read` will return nonzero if the delimiter isn't found, and you aren't using `-d`, this will effectively detect whether there was a newline found in output.